# How to add a button to a pre-existing tab on ribbon (C#)?

Tags: c#, ribbon, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've successfully created a new tab and put it next to the pre-existing ones. Then I realized that I'll only have one button on it, so it makes more sense (for now) to put it on the Home tab. Didn't really get that to work though.

I've tried to follow the guides and walk-troughs. I've got me an XML and changed its XML to the following.

```
<tabs>
  <!--<tab idMso="TabAddIns">-->
  <tab idMso="TabHome">
    <group id="group1" label="Hazaa!">
      <box id="box1" />
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

When I run the project I get no changes to the UI, so I guess that either:

1. the XML is not read at all,
2. the name `TabHome` is wrong (at least for Outlook 2010),
3. the attribute `idMso` is wrong (at least for Outlook 2010) or
4. other/combination of any of the mentioned.

What can I do to alter the ribbon? (Outlook 2010/VSTO/VS 2010/.NET 4).

Comment: Is the above the complete XML? There should be a `<customUI>` tag as rootnode and a `<ribbon>` tag inside it, no? Otherwise I think your XML code will be ignored by Outlook. In other words, alternative #1.

Comment: Yes, I've got those too. Just didn't want to post huge chucks of text. My assumption was that the name targets wrong tab (or none at all). As I commented on your terrific reply, the assumption turned out to be right.

Answer (score 20):

The attribute `idMso` is correct, but the id for the tab you want is `TabMail`. You can find a [packed set of Excel-files containing lists of Office 2010 control IDs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) on MSDN. Then, as mentioned in a comment to the question, your sample XML may be missing the customUI and ribbon-tags. (Disclaimer: I haven't customized the ribbon in Outlook, only Word, Excel and PowerPoint, but I would guess they work the same?)

Try something like the this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabMail">
                <group id="group1" label="Hazaa!">
                    <box id="box1" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: That **was** it. Very gotcha-ish, I may add. For future reference - how can I list all the names of all the tabs currently installed/visible/available in the Outlook/Word/Any other ribbonized software? I saw a hint somewhere that I could go to QAT and check them in the tool tips but that's only good for the components **inside** the tabs. The very tabs themselves show no tool tips...

Comment: I think there is a reference for it somewhere on msdn, but I can't find it at the moment...

Comment: Btw, you can mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark beside the answer, with an upvote if you wish.

Comment: Yes, I wish. I'm just trying to look up some extra info to put in so that the next poor soul that will runs into this problem won't have to ask a follow-up questions. I'm trying to google for a few of the common tab names but that doesn't give me any link to a list. Someone suggested that I download a file with all the names but it's an EXE and I can't see the point of distributing a text file as an executable so I'm assuming that the tip was wrong or misunderstood, until someone savvy tells me otherwise.

Comment: OK, I think I found it. The exe mentioned is a zip-file with a bunch of excel-files with the IDs for the different office programs. Updating answer with the link!

Comment: Now a question remains - what if I want to refer a tab that isn't a default MS-tab on the ribbon? E.g. CRM Dynamics adds one and how I'm supposed to get its name?!

Comment: Maybe [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/615482/1490783) can help you with IDs for the thirdparty tab? Leave a comment here if you get it to work...

Comment: None of the Excel files with the Office 2010 control IDs show TabMail as a valid idMso. Or did I miss it?

Comment: It's in OutlookExplorerControls.xlsx... :)

Comment: the link no longer works here is a good resource https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a button to appear in an existing ribbon, in Visual Studio, here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608628.aspx#Anchor_2

in your case change the **OfficeId** to **TabMail**

Answer (score 3):

For people frustrated that none of the other answers seem to be working, go to the properties for the Ribbon itself and set the `RibbonType` to `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` (or whichever context[s] you want to see the control in).  It's a crucial step that's easy to overlook.

Then follow the other instructions to set `OfficeId` to `TabMail`.

Additionally, Office 2016 Fluent Control Identifiers can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50745

Comment: I was wondering why my controls weren't showing up until I happened across your answer. Thanks! Saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Edited. Sorry, gave a dnn link. You want office and you want c#.

Here's a StackOverflow answer in VBA... 
[How to get Ribbon custom Tabs IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615482/how-to-get-ribbon-custom-tabs-ids)

```
AccessibleChildren _
            Lib "oleacc.dll" _
                (ByVal paccContainer As Object, _
                 ByVal iChildStart As Long, _
                 ByVal cChildren As Long, _
                       rgvarChildren As Variant, _
                       pcObtained As Long) _
            As Long
```

Which in C# translates to

```
[Lib "oleacc.dll"]
Long AccessibleChildren(object paccContainer, 
                        long iChildStart, 
                        long cChildren, 
                        object rgvarChildren, 
                        long pcObtained)...
```

I never tried it, so not sure it works.

From all other documentation, it seems you simply get the ribbon object, and in it iterate (with foreach) through all the children