# How to programmatically add a add-in button in Outlook Meeting Tab?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have searched all over but couldn't find solution to this.

I have to add a add-in button in Meeting tab of Meeting Window in Outlook.
Below are the methods that I already tried:

- Method1 : Ribbon (XML)

I added ribbon(XML) to my project but I could only find idMso for New 'Add-In' Tab and not for meeting Tab.

- Method2: Ribbon (Visual Designer)

I already have added the button in Add-In Tab using C# VSTO. But I want to add that button in Meeting tab programmatically and not manually edit the ribbon.

[Current position of Button in 'Add-In' Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dree4.png)

[Required position of Button in 'Meeting' Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdhT4.png)

I am using MS Outlook 2016 and Visual Studio 2015.

Can someone please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489832/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-pre-existing-tab-on-ribbon-c

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed OfficeId to 'TabAppointment' instead of Tab Meeting. Is there any way to set the index position of that button. I mean how do I get my button group to the first position, before all other groups?

Comment: I believe this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-customize-a-built-in-tab?view=vs-2017) on how to customize built in tabs will be useful to you.

You will need to find the ControlId of the group that you want to place your button before. The linked documentation has a link to these ControlIds